# Ground Overlays at Google Static Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Is there an option to put ground overlay at google static map as you can see it 
on google maps JavaScript API ?

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/groundoverlay-simple

Comment: There is no option to add Ground Overlays to [static maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro)